# Accuracy decreases with increasing batches in neural network

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am training a large dataset using Keras neural network. I observed that the accuracy is high in initial batches but it decreases with higher batches.

Following is my code-

```
model_nn = keras.Sequential()
model_nn.add(Dense(352, input_dim=28, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(384, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(288, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(448, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(320, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model_nn.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model_nn.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001), metrics=['accuracy'])
history=model_nn.fit(X_train1, y_train1,validation_data=(X_test,y_test),epochs=300, batch_size=100, verbose = 1 )
```

Below is the accuracy in starting and final batches-

```
    1/80410 [..............................] - ETA: 24:12 - loss: 0.4017 - accuracy: 0.8500
    2/80410 [..............................] - ETA: 1:14:13 - loss: 0.4294 - accuracy: 0.8300
    3/80410 [..............................] - ETA: 1:24:09 - loss: 0.4797 - accuracy: 0.7933
    ...
    80408/80410 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5229 - accuracy: 0.7531
    80409/80410 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5229 - accuracy: 0.7531
```

I observe a similar trend in many epochs, What could be the reason behind this?

Comment: These types of problems are discussed at length on CrossValidated. For example:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164876/what-is-the-trade-off-between-batch-size-and-number-of-iterations-to-train-a-neu

Comment: Curiously, your loss is also increasing, which is very weird. But.... you should check "epochs", not batches. Also, the `kernel_regularizer` might be affecting this. You may check without it and see if it gets better (if so, then you might want to try lower coefficients for the regularizer)

Comment: I can see that the accuracy from the start to finish of one epoch. Could you send the training history over a number of epochs?